# Invalid image when using force download in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I use download helper in codeigneter,, when i download file jpeg and open it,, it becomes invalid...

What should i do..

Thank you...

Controller

```
function downloadSuratElektronik($file)
{
    $this->load->helper('download');
    $file_data = file_get_contents(base_url()."data/".$file);
    $file_name = $file;
    force_download($file_name, $file_data);
}
```

Model

```
 function getSuratKeluar(){
    $data = $this->db->get('surat_keluar');
    if ($data->num_rows() > 0){
        foreach ($data->result() as $row){
            $hasil[]=$row;
        }
        return $hasil;
    }
```

}

View

```
 <table>
    <tr>
    <td>File Upload</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    foreach ($hasil as $data) :
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><a href="<?=base_url();?>main/downloadSuratElektronik/<?=$data->link_upload?>">/<?=$data->link_upload?></a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: when i open the jpg file that i have been download before,, the image just blank,, and error,, even i can download it and the file name is correct,,, what should i do ?? thank you...

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem, i fixed it using other method... if u still want it

```
$file_name = "picture.jpg" 
$file_path = "your path" 
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream'); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name");
ob_clean(); flush(); 
readfile($file_path);
```